# changing the boot logo on embedded linux (angstrom)

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded, embedded-linux

i have am3517 based embedded board and i have installed my own kernel and filesystem compiled with angstrom toolchain. Now i want to change the bootscreen logo?

Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: worth reading: http://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/linux/f/354/t/109387.aspx

Comment: Do you mean the one @ your boot loader or the linux penguin (or similar) that comes up during boot?

Comment: i mean the penguin. but if i can change the both of them it would be awesome